# Evitar cierre de un JOptionPane vacío

Tags: java, joptionpane

Tengo un JOptionPane que requiere confirmación *sí* o *no* para efectuar un descuento, el problema es que el usuario puede cerrar esa ventana y no muestra ningún error, al contrario, directamente no se aplica ningún descuento.
Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma para evitar que esa ventana se cierre sin ingresar un dato válido.
Les dejo la porción de código:

```java
int confirm2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿El trabajador tiene hijos menores a cargo?",null ,JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Comment: Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio (lo primero que menciona es que no es un foro ;) ). Ten en cuenta que el IDE (Eclipse) en este caso no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando tu elijes el boton **YES** confirm2 sera 0,si elijes **NO** sera 1 y si cierras la venta con **X** sera -1,basado en ello puede hacer uso de un bucle doWhile() para evitar que la venta se cierre,en caso no se elija entre **YES** o **NO**

```
int confirm2=0;
do{
confirm2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿El trabajador tiene hijos menores a cargo?",null ,JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
}while(confirm2==-1);
```